# How to edit Aspnet_isapi.dll mapping in IIS 7.5?

Tags: iis-7.5

I am trying to host WCF service svc files on IIS. Whenever I browse the svc files through IIS hosting it just shows the text contained in svc files in the browser. I went through few msdn links to change the mapping of dll but those documents are for IIS 6.0 and before. Its the first time I am working on IIS and I am not getting how to add view the dll mapping in IIS 7.5 manager.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa751792.aspx

Follow the Windows Vista part to enable Windows Communication Foundation Activation Components under .NET Framework 3.5.1.

Comment: Thank you Lex. I also came across another link which helped me to figure out this stuff. For future references go through this link a well. [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms752252(v=vs.90).aspx)

Comment: In fact when you enable the feature, the command line is executed in the background. Well, running the command line directly has no side effect though :)